# How to debug Android emulator with ionic?

Tags: android, ionic-framework

Using ionic, I am writing an app which I am trying to test with an Android emulator. I can successfully build and even add the app to the emulator but when I click the app it immediately dies before even loading the home page.

Is there anyway to debug this? I have tried running consolelogs and serverlogs but nothing is getting outputted. I have also tried debugging through Chrome (https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging). But even though the device shows up in the list it does not have any of the options such as 'inspect', 'focus tab', 'reload', nor 'close'. It just displays the emulator's name.

Comment: What is the Android version? I think you need a new version of Android to debug using chrome

Comment: I have the latest Android Studios and am using Android API Level 24

Comment: You can open the project with Android studio but you can debug the native part of your application. You can debug the CordovaActivity class

Comment: try to open the project that contains CordovaLib in Android studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `adb logcat` in a separate terminal.

As you run the emulator your terminal should populate with logs.