# Ionic use angular HTTP POST does not call to API on Android Emulator

Tags: angular, spring-boot, ionic2

I have a Ionic2 and spring boot api demo, and it is working well on browser but when I run it on Android Emulator and try to test the demo, it only works for HTTP GET, while HTTP POST does not call to API,
here is my HTTP post:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { RequestOptions, Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Events, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService { 
    /**
     * Constructs the Authentication Service
     * @param {Http} http     
     * @param {Events} events

     */
    constructor(
        private http: Http,       
        private events: Events,       
        private alertCtrl: AlertController        
    ) {}  

    private createHeader(): RequestOptions {
        let options = new RequestOptions();        
        options.headers = new Headers({
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        });
        return options;
    } 

    private login(): Observable<string> {
        let authUrl = 'http://192.168.43.231:8084/api/user/test';
        let data = {'phone':'8888888','password':'abc'}
        return this.http.post(authUrl, JSON.stringify(data), this.createHeader()).map((data: any) => {
            this.presentAlert(data);           
           return '';
        });
    }

presentAlert(data: any) {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Low battery',
      subTitle: data,
      buttons: ['Dismiss']
    });
    alert.present();
  }
}
```

I also have the proxies in

> ionic.config.json

like that:

```
{
  "name": "ionic app",
  "app_id": "",
  "type": "ionic-angular",
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/api",
      "proxyUrl": "http://192.168.43.231:8084/api"
    }
  ],
  "integrations": {
    "cordova": {}
  }
}
```

and I have api testing:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/user/test", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = {
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> test(@RequestBody LoginForm login) {
        System.out.println("This test successful");
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Test", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

If I change get function it work for me.

```
let authUrl = 'http://192.168.43.231:8084/api/user/test';
        return this.http.get(authUrl).map((data: any) => {
            this.presentAlert(data);                     
           return '';
        });
    }
```

and services

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/user/test", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> test() {
        System.out.println("This test successful");
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Test", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Comment: replace `JSON.stringify(data)` with `data` in your post body.

Comment: thanks, I also try it but still get issue.

Comment: ok, are you able to see the browser logs on the emulator ? Are there any errors ?

Comment: I do not know how to debug on device app or emulator, so I tried to add alert box but it does not show.

Comment: you could try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37994511/how-to-debug-android-emulator-with-ionic) if you're running it via android studio, or try [this](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-view-console-log-in-the-emulator/17902/7)

Comment: I config android emulator and run command line: ionic cordova run android.

Comment: run with `ionic cordova run android -c -- -d` and see the logs, you should see what is wrong.

Comment: this is message fail: [18:02:54]  console.error: ERROR [object Object]

Comment: Not related, but you really should update to using the `HttpClient` instead ;)

Comment: ... and try to not use the proxy in the emulator.

Comment: @AJT_82, it same problem, does angular http work on device or emulator? should I work with ionic native http ?

Comment: it is resolved from api, I config CORS and when run on emulator, it should be remove from api. thanks for your reponses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see any issues with your code apart from the fact, that you pass a string as a request body for HTTP POST. Apparently, Spring tries to parse input request body as a single String object, thus not finding any suitable controller to handle the request.
Replace your `JSON.stringify(data)` with `data` object and you should be fine.

Comment: I have tried, but It is only work for browser, the android emulator does not work.